# I am in want of

Tags: grammar

> I am in **a** want of. #1
>
> I am in want of.   #2

A) Would you ever say #1?

B) Why would you want to omit "a" in front of "want"? If you say "I'm in a want", what would make you feel that it is wrong? You use the word "hurry" with an article in the expression "*I am in a hurry*" and that seems odd to me. If you think about the logic which applies to "want", do you feel that "You are in **a** want of" is dead wrong?

Comment: I have only said "I am in a want of" once during my entire life.  It is dead wrong.

Comment: Here's an interesting Google Ngram showing the rise and fall of "in want": [Google Ngram: in want](https://goo.gl/XnBlIx), which started declining about 1820.  The following shows some likely culprits of the demise of "in want" [Google Ngram: in want,I want,would like,ready for,desire for, needed](https://goo.gl/NVjEaC).  It shows "needed" steadily increasing from about 1820.  The other constructions also show increased usage, though it's difficult to see due to the skyrocketing "needed".  Here's a graph of all the prior phrases without "needed": [Ngram](https://goo.gl/qWXlJP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literate native speakers will be familiar with this usage from [the opening line of Jane Austen's *Pride & Prejudice*](http://www.pemberley.com/janeinfo/ppv1n01.html)...

> *It is a truth universally acknowledged, that a single man in possession of a good fortune must **be in want of** a wife*

...but that was written in 1797. Anyone who wanted to use this construction today would almost certainly go for *X is in **need** of Y*. But even that's somewhat poetic/literary - in normal conversational English we'd be much more likely to say *X needs Y*.

Comment: You've made it clear that _in want of_ was used by native speakers in the 18th & 19th Centuries and can be understood nowadays. I was surprised about the other constructions _have a want for_ and _in want for_ and asked whether they could be used at least in the Middle Ages or they were never valid in English.